# Need to merge mulitple unix txt lines

Tags: awk

Hi I need to merge multiple lines too one line in txt using `awk`,have tried different things but can't get the result I'm after! An example;

need it to go from this:

```
11 01 30 31 33 37 39 39 30 30 30 30 30 38 31 34 

36 06 02 00 00 00 06 06 03 00 00 00 01 03 06 28 

06 09 00 00 00 00 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 31 

20 20 20 20 20 20 20 30 31 33 37 39 39 30 30 30 

30 30 38 31 34 36 20 
11 01 30 31 33 37 39 39 30 30 30 30 30 38 31 34 

36 06 02 00 39 ff c3 06 03 00 00 00 02 03 06 28 

06 09 00 00 00 00 00 00 0d 48 1b 03 f8 13 01 52 

b4 18 ff fc 46 29 00 00 06 27 02 ca a0 00 00 63 

07 00 02 77 f5 0f 01 1a 12 1d 2f
```

to this:

```
11 01 30 31 33 37 39 39 30 30 30 30 30 38 31 34 36 06 02 00 00 00 06 060300 00 00 01 03 06 28 06 09 00 00 00 00 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 31 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 30 31 33 37 39 39 30 30 30 30 30 38 31 34 36 20 

11 01 30 31 33 37 39 39 30 30 30 30 30 38 31 34 36 06 02 00 39 ff c3 06 03 00 00 00 02 03 06 28 06 09 00 00 00 00 00 00 0d 48 1b 03 f8 13 01 52 b4 18 ff fc 46 29 00 00 06 27 02 ca a0 00 00 63 07 00 02 77 f5 0f 01 1a 12 1d 2f
```

Comment: What determines where one hex-string ends and the next one begins? It appears you have two in your example.

Answer (score 1):

It is trivial with `awk`:

```
awk 1 ORS=' '
```

Answer (score 0):

See @jimmij for `awk`. You could also just change newlines into spaces:

```
tr '\n' ' ' <input >output
```